# HTML.Encode localization with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, localization

How can I escape localized string encoding:

```
<%= Html.Encode("ÆØÅ") %> from rendering  &#198;&#216;&#197;
```

is there another way to encode localized strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's being encoded twice - are you using this in a HtmlHelper call?

```
// this will display&#198;&#216;&#197; as Html.TextBox encodes the
// value passed to it so it's encoded twice in this line
<%=Html.TextBox("sdfsdf", Html.Encode("ÆØÅ"))%><br />

// this will display ÆØÅ
<%= Html.Encode("ÆØÅ") %><br />

// As will this
<%=Html.TextBox("sdfsdf", "ÆØÅ")%><br />
```

Comment: Hmm - this works fine for me:
<%= Html.ActionLink("ÆØÅ", "Details")%>
Not sure why it's not working for you, thats odd..

Comment: BTW: there's bug in MVC View file template. It's saved without BOM, so if you plan to use it as UTF-8 then I recommend to save as UTF-8 with BOM. Otherwise it will use system default encoding.